# a one-stop shop for all things definition lists has to be -- meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> **A one-stop shop for all things definition lists has to be** the excellent article “Definition lists—misused or misunderstood?” (www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/definition/) on the hugelyuseful Max Design web site. There you will also find many brilliant CSS treatments of definition lists including simple image galleries and more tailored formatting.

**all thing definition lists** obviously means **anything that has to do with definition lists**. Great. But I don't know how I should understand **a one-stop shop ~ HAS TO BE the excellent article ~**. Does it mean that this article is so good that it must be the best article on that subject?

Comment: FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_stop_shop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a one-stop shop

in this usage means a place (in this case *the excellent article “Definition lists—misused or misunderstood?”*) where everything you need can be found. Not really a place, but you would find any information on the subject that you need.

Literally, *a one-stop shop* would be a store where you can buy everything you need without going elsewhere, hence the term "one-stop".